# Writing text from BeautifulSoup to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to parse the currency table in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies . The problem is I am not getting the output in correct format. I want the output to be of the form :

```
country currency
```

in case of multiple currency the currency should either be in next line or space after the previous currency. Here is how far I was able to get

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies"
soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
i=1
fr=open("out.txt","w")
for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr'):
    if i==1:
        i+=1
        continue


    temp_row=row.findAll('td')
    print len(temp_row)
    """Handling the case for multiple currencies"""
    if(len(temp_row)==5):
        ans=row.findAll('td')[0].findAll('a')
        if len(ans)==0 :
            ans=row.findAll('td')[0].contents
        else :
            ans=row.findAll('td')[0].findAll('a')[0].contents
        fr.write("      "+str(ans)+"\n")
    else:
        first=row.findAll('td')[0].findAll('a')[0].contents

        ans=row.findAll('td')[1].findAll('a')
        if len(ans)==0 :
            ans=row.findAll('td')[1].contents
        else :
            ans=row.findAll('td')[1].findAll('a')[0].contents
    #print first
        fr.write(str(first)+"    "+str(ans)+"\n")
```

the problem is I want strings to when I am using contents[0] instead of content it is giving:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

error I am also not getting the output in exact format . The file out.txt has to read by some other program written in VB so I want the file format to be as close to the format specified as possible. Also please help me in cleaning out the code.

Update:

I get the following error using encode:

```
 File "D:/scrap.py", line 33, in <module>
    first = first.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 992, in encode
    u = self.decode(indent_level, encoding, formatter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1056, in decode
    indent_space = (' ' * (indent_level - 1))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Update: Added the following lines in the beginning to make it work

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: I think we're missing something, somewhere in your code it seems a mathematical equation is being performed on your string.

Comment: How are you handeling the case when the name of the currency consists of two words? Such as `Russian Ruble`. For Russia, the output string should be (according to your spec) `Russia Russian Ruble`. How would the reader know if this is one or two currencies? Wouldn't a csv file be a better option?

Comment: @SteinarLima Good point looks like I have to add the currency code to the list. But first I need to parse the page properly. Thanks for help. do you have any alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem as you if trying to decode the strings to ascii. Is there any special reason you don't want utf8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with utf chars in your file, you can convert the unicode objects to utf encoded strings using `encode('utf8')`.

Answer (score 1):

to see if you're getting solid results try to ignore the unicode for a moment and see what the result is.

```
first = first.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
ans = ans.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

print first + " " + ans
```

Comment: i changed first to str(first) ans ans to str(ans) the error for unsupported type vanished but the previous error is still present